# Как выровнять по центру несколько дивов?

Tags: css

Внутри див-блока разположены несколько дивов. Как их разместить по центру в одну строку?
Заранее количество дивов неизвестно. Они могут добавляться или удаляться в админке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/4jA4X/

Comment: Еще контейнеру можно добавить white-space: nowrap; чтобы айтемы при нехватки места не переносились на новую строку. Пробелы, которые образуются между инлайн-блоками, как между словами, можно убить такими способами: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/
Очень полезно прочитать статью http://habrahabr.ru/post/117109/ для понимания инлайн-блоков.

Comment: Я насколько понимаю, display: inline-block IE не понимается? До версии 8.

Comment: Не понимаются. Мои соболезнования, если заказчик требует поддержку этого браузера.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к собалезнованиям :) Но инлайн-блок можно заставить работать в ie6 ie7. Ознакомьтесь со статьей на хабре в предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: Да нет, заказчик ничего не требует. Это я для себя делаю.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, почитаю.